# Stop ad-blocker from breaking internal site

Tags: javascript, adblock

I have an internal system that runs as a web application. There are no adverts in this application.

One of the things our users can do is post adverts *from* our app to various third-party advertising platforms (these are specific to our industry).

Some of our users use various ad blocker extensions.

Because these JS components include words like *"Advertise"* they **consistently** get blocked by ad-blocking extensions.

However, these scripts are internal to our site, served locally from the same CORS protected domain, they aren't adverts to block.

We want our users to be able to use these extensions for regular web browsing.

How do we mark a JS script that we are serving as safely part of our application in a way that ad-blockers will understand?

Comment: I think if there is a special keyword to make adblocker ignore it all ads widget will use it to be ignored by the adblocker

Comment: I had a similar problem - had a route in my API that starts with `/analytics` and various extensions would block the request from completing (anti tracking and ad blocker extensions). The way I solved it was by changing the route to `/reports`, couldn't find any other solution.

Comment: If this is internal program can you ask your users to ignore adblock for some website if can.

Comment: If you could somehow "mark" your own code as "not an ad , bro, I swear!" and have ad blockers respect that - then the people trying to get around my ad blocker to show me _actual_ ads, would already be doing the same. You should rather advice your users that they should disable any ad blockers for your site - for example Facebook is doing exactly that in their own ad creation web interface.

Comment: There is a way to force the user to disable their ad-blockers on your site - really easy to do, just add a script tag to your HTML and that does it, but I do not condone using such tactics. I respect people's decision to block ads and protect themselves from companies collecting their data.

Comment: you can just rename it or send 1 pr for filters

Comment: @Dimitar these ad blocker detection methods can be bypassed easily because the site is yours but the browser is the user's

Comment: @TachibanaShin They can be bypassed by users who have technical knowledge (IT skills or just computer enthusiasts) which make up a small portion of the population, so unless OP has majority visitors who are versed in technology, I don't think he would mind 5% of the people to bypass his ad blocker detector.

Comment: @Dimitar I can block users from using ad blockers, or any browser extensions, but I'd rather not. We probably benefit from them seeing fewer ads.

Comment: @CBroe But all those ads will be external scripts - this JS and everything it loads is internal to the site (also no media)

Comment: @TachibanaShin I can't - the text in the component needs to include words like "advert" - its a component so my users can _create_ adverts.

Comment: @kennarddh only if the ad blockers are really dumb - just block any script with the word "advert" in it is really naïve. I could write a really obnoxious ad script and just obfuscate the hell out of it. Surely it needs to check other things? Ads are always third party domains (these days, the banner you host yourself appears long gone) and always set cookies and make remote `fetch` requests, all things you can't obfuscate. I could add a checksum of the control to my header (or the like) that ads really can't do.

Comment: @Keith what ad blockers do is right there are millions of sites with inline ad scripts out there and if they give in then hundreds of millions of users will be affected

Comment: @Keith please try to include ad blocking rule set in your question i will try to solve it at least in Adguard

Comment: @TachibanaShin I can just add a static advert image to my site, call it `123.jpg`, make it a link to an external site that's paying me and boom, all ad blockers evaded. I don't think those are the problem though - that isn't the toxic dark-pattern behaviour that _needs_ blocking. We've noticed our internal JS being blocked by multiple ad blockers, I've no idea how to get the rule sets in all of them or which rule has been tripped - our users are not technical (all we get is "I go to post an ad and it crashes").